# Find daily slope OR previous minus current week difference

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data:

| week | sale |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 50 |
| 20 | 20 |
| 21 | 10 |
| 21 | 10 |
| 22 | 5 |
| 22 | 5 |

Desired result:

| week | sale | change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 50 | any |
| 20 | 20 | any |
| 21 | 10 | -50 |
| 21 | 10 | -50 |
| 22 | 5 | -10 |
| 22 | 5 | -10 |

Where:
Week 20 total = 70,
Week 21 total = 20,
Week 22 total = 10

Diff for week 21 = 20-70 = -50
Diff for week 22 = 10-20 = -10

Note: "any" = can be anything (i.e. 0 or null)

Answer (score 1):

Calculated column

```
Column 2 =
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[week] ) ) - 1
VAR _2 =
    SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[week] = _1 ), 'Table'[sale] )
VAR _3 =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[sale] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[week] ) )
VAR _4 =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _2 ) = TRUE (), BLANK (), _3 )
RETURN
    _4
```

Measure

```
currentWeekTotal:= SUM('Table'[sale])

prevWeekTotal:= 
VAR _1 = MAX('Table'[week])-1
VAR _2 = SUMX(FILTER(ALL('Table'),'Table'[week]=_1),'Table'[sale])
RETURN _2

change:= IF([prevWeekTotal]=BLANK(),BLANK(),[currentWeekTotal]-[prevWeekTotal])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for a calculated column :

```
change = 
VAR _firstweek = MIN ( 'Table'[week] )
VAR _thisweek = 'Table'[week]
VAR _thisweeksales = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[sale] ) , ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[week] ) )
VAR _lastweeksales = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[sale] ) , ALL ( 'Table' ) , 'Table'[week] = _thisweek - 1 )
VAR _diff = IF ( _thisweek <> _firstweek , _thisweeksales - _lastweeksales )
RETURN _diff
```

This also handles skipped weeks that are not the first week.